# MustOverride Properties with mixed access level Get / Set

Tags: vb.net, oop

Visual Basic allows for properties with mixed access levels, for example

```
Public Property Name() as String
    Get

    End Get

    Friend Set(ByVal value As String)

    End Set
End Property
```

Is there a way to define a `MustOverride` property with mixed getter/setter access level?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmm... you can in C# very easily:

```
public abstract string Foo { get; protected set; }
```

Unfortunately Reflector creates invalid VB when I decompile that...

EDIT: Having looked at a few bits of documentation, I *suspect* you can't do this :( The [MustOverride documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyb29zk8.aspx) states:

> Incomplete Declaration. When you
>   specify MustOverride, you do not
>   supply any additional lines of code
>   for the property or procedure, not
>   even the End Function, End Property,
>   or End Sub statement.

That suggests to me that you can't specify the different access levels :(

Comment: This is correct.  VB has no syntax support for a mustoverride and mixed accessibility modifiers.